# List View Background Become white when i touch and scroll but i want to tranparent?

Tags: android, listview, background

i want to transparent the background when i touch on listview here i put the image in first what i need and in 2 image what currently with me so how to set it 
first image which i want and in 2 image when i touch on listview is become white after touch and scroll

[image]

2 image is wrong i want first image type how to disable the white background on touch in listview
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use these tag in ListView

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
 android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

User this.

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```